# SwiftUi Decoding JSON

Tags: json, swift, decode

I am new to Swift and SwiftUi and I am trying to Decode a JSON file. I know that I have to use CodingKeys but I don't know how to do it when the key is a date.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "2020-09-01": [
        "Tuesday",
        [],
        "N"
    ],
    "2020-09-02": [
        "Wednesday",
        [
          "12:00p"
        ],
        "N"
    ]
}
```

And my model looks like this:

```
struct TimeStamp: Codable {
    var t =  [TimeStampForCurrentDay]()
}

struct TimeStampForCurrentDay: Codable {
    let day: String
    let times: [String]
    let type: String
}
```

And I get this Error

Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "t", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "t", intValue: nil) ("t").", underlyingError: nil))

when I try to decode with this function

```
try! JSONDecoder().decode(TimeStamp.self, from: responseData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a dictionary of type `[String: [Any]]` which is a little hard to decode. Either you use `JSONSerialization` to decode directly to this dictionary type

```
do {
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: [Any]]
    //...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But if the order of the values in each array is always the same, that is day/times/type then we can decode using a custom init to get a dictionary of type `[String: TimeStampForCurrentDay]`

```
struct TimeStampForCurrentDay: Codable {
    let day: String
    let times: [String]
    let type: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        day = try container.decode(String.self)
        times = try container.decode([String].self)
        type = try container.decode(String.self)
    }
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: TimeStampForCurrentDay].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you the second code is what i was looking for. Have a nice day!